# AutoFilter with SpecialCells to Delete Rows Also Removes Header Row

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to delete rows based on the value in a column. I know there a several ways to do this but I'm wondering why this method ends up deleting the header row, as well. Do I need to specify a different range?

```
Sub DeleteForeign()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Excel.Range
'
' Choose entire column
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' Changing the range from Cells(1, "D") to Cells(2, "D") keeps the header intact,
' but deletes the next row which should be left since it has the value, "US"
        Set Rng = .Range(Cells(1, "D"), Cells(LastRow, "D"))
    End With
' This construct avoids looping which would be time-consuming for long lists
' Looking for country code, "US", and to delete all others
    With Rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>US", Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code: 
The only difference here is that I am re-defining the range before deleting the filtered rows.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, "D"), Cells(LastRow, "D")).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>US", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range(Cells(2, "D"), Cells(LastRow, "D")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData  

End Sub
```

Comment: Not only did that work properly, but the code is much more concise.
Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Change it from:  `Cells(1, "D")` to: `Cells(2, "D")`

Does that do what you want?  In Excel VBA, as well as other environments, it's always (row,column).  See the link below for more info.

https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2021718&seqNum=7